# Json download link (google spreadsheet) for specific sheet

Tags: json, google-sheets

I am currently using this link to download a Json document of the spreadsheet: 
https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key= My key is here

This link only downloads the first sheet. How do I specify the link to download another sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it myself. By using this link you can only download one sheet. This sheet is always the first sheet in the whole google spreadsheet document.

Comment: If you're donloading it as a Json file, you can only download the first sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `sheet` parameter to get data from specific sheet, e.g.

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?sheet=Sheet2&key=tHeKeY
```